# Tortoise SVN, how to filter checkout files by extension

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working on several asp.Net websites with several web designers. I want only the programmers can checkout the code files ( *.cs in asp.net) and let the designers checkout any other files. 
So, I think that filter files by user/extension it's the behavior I need.
Is this possible ? If not, how whould you aproach my issue ?

Comment: what i do know is that you can source files, http://www.tortoisecvs.org/faq.html#exclusive

Answer (score 1):

1. With SVN there is no ability to checkout by extension.
2. If your intention is only to combine some files in one folder - then you can use SVN externals (there are drawbacks, but anyway).
3. If your intention is to limit access - you should separate code files from other files (move), change project settings, etc and stick to the [path based authorization](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) .